# Using Diagrams library in haskell (draw binary trees)

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, functional-programming, binary-tree

I am trying to use the Haskell Diagrams library for drawing binary trees.

This is my tree type:

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node { label :: a, left,right :: Tree a }

leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf a = Node a Empty Empty
```

This is a random tree:

```
t0 = Node 1 (Node 2 (leaf 3) (leaf 4))   (Node 5 (leaf 6) (leaf 7))
```

For drawing a circle with a char in the middle I am using this simple function (works fine):

```
diagNode :: String -> Diag
```

Here is my code to draw the binary tree:

```
diagTree :: Show s => Tree s -> Diag
diagTree Empty = diagNode "Empty"

diagTree (Node x Empty Empty) = connectOutside "X" "L" $
                                connectOutside "X" "R" $
          nx
          ===
      (nl ||| nr) # center
  where
    nx = named "X" ( diagNode (show x) )  
    nl = named "L" (diagNode "Empty" )
    nr = named "R" (diagNode "Empty" )  

diagTree (Node x left right) = connectOutside "X" "L" $
                               connectOutside "X" "R" $
          nx
          ===
      (nl ||| nr) # center
  where
    nx = named "X" ( diagNode (show x) ) 
    nl = named "L" (diagTree left )
    nr = named "R" (diagTree right )
```

[image]

**You can see my code works only for the last "leafs", but it doesn't connect the upper nodes with the nodes below.** I think the problem is, that I am calling diagTree recursively.

How can I fix this problem??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is you're naming giving the inner nodes the same names so `connectOutside` connects the first names it finds (which happen to be the last nodes in your tree). You can solve this by giving each node a unique name depending on its position:

```
diagTree :: Show s => Tree s -> Diagram Rasterific
diagTree = go [] where
  go nm Empty        = diagNode  "Empty" # named nm
  go nm (Node x l r) = 
    connectOutside nm nmL .
    connectOutside nm nmR $
          nx
          ===
      (nl ||| nr) # centerX
    where
      (nmL, nmR) = ('L':nm, 'R':nm)
      nx = diagNode (show x) # named nm 
      nl = go nmL l # named nmL
      nr = go nmR r # named nmR
```

with

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node { label :: a, left,right :: Tree a }
  deriving Show

leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf a = Node a Empty Empty

diagNode :: String -> Diagram Rasterific
diagNode txt = text txt # fontSizeL 0.4 <> circle 1 & pad 2
```

I get [image: tree]